# Understanding response message of nslookup debug query

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, nslookup

I need to understand what following response message really means. I tried googling it but couldn't get specific answer. what does Questions,Answers,Authority Records and Additional Records really mean?

**REQUEST QUERY: *nslookup -debug www.google.com***

**RESPONSE MESSAGE:**

**QUESTIONS:**

www.google.com, type = A, class = IN

**ANSWERS:**

->  www.google.com

internet address = 64.233.166.106

ttl = 229

->  www.google.com

internet address = 64.233.166.147

ttl = 229

->  www.google.com

internet address = 64.233.166.105

ttl = 229

->  www.google.com

internet address = 64.233.166.99

ttl = 229

->  www.google.com

internet address = 64.233.166.103

ttl = 229

**AUTHORITY RECORDS:**

**ADDITIONAL RECORDS:**

Thank you,
Brother

Answer (score 0):

**QUESTION FIELD:** There is always one question in a DNS message; it includes the domain name and the requested datatype and class. There is never more than one question in a DNS message.

**ANSWER FIELD:** This section contains the resource records that answer the question. There can be more than one resource record in the response. For example, if the host is multihomed, there will be more than one address resource record.

**AUTHORITY RECORDs**:The authority section is where name server records are returned.

**ADDITIONAL RECORDS**:The additional records section adds information that may complete the information included in other sections. For instance, if a name server is listed in the authority section, the name server's address may be included in the additional records section. After all, to contact the name server, you need to have its address.